# E: Unable to locate package redis-server

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I am using Ubuntu machine (14.04.1). I have installed docker daemon (1.12.3 and go version: 1.6.3). I have written a dockerfile which will download redis DB. But it is throwing me following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package redis-server
```

I tried redis also when redis-server did not work. It again throws the same error.

```
E: Unable to locate package redis
```

Contents of Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server

EXPOSE 6379
```

I am able to run apt-get update but not able to install redis-server or redis. Docker's registry is docker hub. I am able to download redis in local (`sudo apt-get install -y redis-server`), outside docker but with docker I am not able to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am able to install redis-server as well as python. I added *RUN apt-get update* in Dockerfile. It updated and got redis installed. And there was one more thing in my case. I had already run  'apt-get update' which created an image before. All the time it was referring to the image and was not updating. Hence I used --no-cache=True and made it.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get -y install redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy like apt-get install:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis

By the way - You can use redis docker image, or look inside Dockerfile to check how they did it:
https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/
https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/6cb8a8015f126e2a7251c5d011b86b657e9febd6/3.0/Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you Barat. I am getting same error with python too. I was able to download python before.

Comment: Seriously over a year and ubuntu still doesn't have a proper installer :o